# Cross database query....Mysql databases

Tags: mysql, perl, perl-module

Need to take each value from a column( say string) of a table (bucket) in Database1, then query for the same value under the same column name and table name in Database2.

is there an option to do that???

Need help...

Comment: can something like this be done?? pls help with syntax... 

        DBI->connect( database1 );
        'SELECT string FROM bucket'
        
         foreach(value in string){
         DBI->connect( database2);
         'SELECT id,name,string FROM bucket where string = string of db1'

Answer (score 1):

You can join the two databases with a statement similar to below. Of course putting in your database informaiton

```
SELECT database1.bucket.stringcolumn, database2.bucket.stringcolumn 
  FROM arbogast.node, mcguffin.node 
  WHERE database1.bucket.stringcolumn = Value 
   AND database1.bucket.stringcolumn = database2.bucket.stringcolumn;
```

Reference: http://www.dottedidesign.com/node/14

Comment: I don't see why not.  You just need to put it in the proper perl syntax.  Check out this link: http://www.tizag.com/perlT/perldbiquery.php

Comment: Please do not link to Tizag. As of early 2012, it is probably the [worst tutorial in the world](http://perl-tutorial.org/rejected/tizag/). - The official documentation is on http://dbi.perl.org/